# Tensorflow: How to encode and read bmp images?

Tags: python, image, tensorflow, bmp

I am trying to read .bmp images, do some augmentation on these, save them to a .tfrecords file and then open the .tfrecords files and use the images for image classification. I know that there is a tf.image.encode_jpeg() and a tf.image.encode_png() function, but there is no tf.image.encode_bmp() function. I know that .bmp images are uncompressed, so I've tried to simply base64-encode, np.tostring() and np.tobytes() the images, but I get the following error when trying to decode these formats:

`tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: channels attribute 3 does not match bits per pixel from file <some long number>`

My take is that tensorflow, in its encoding to jpeg or png, does something extra with the byte encoding of the images; saving information about array dimensionality, etc. However, I am quite clueless about this, so any help would be great!

Some code to show what it is I am trying to achieve:

```
with tf.gfile.FastGFile(filename, 'rb') as f:
    image_data = f.read()
    bmp_data = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.string)
    decode_bmp = tf.image.decode_bmp(self._decode_bmp_data, channels=3)
    augmented_bmp = <do some augmentation on decode_bmp>
    sess = tf.Session()
    np_img = sess.run(augmented_bmp, feed_dict={bmp_data: image_data})
    byte_img = np_img.tostring()

    # Write byte_img to file using tf.train.Example
    writer = tf.python_io.TFRecordWriter(<output_tfrecords_filename>)
    example = tf.train.Example(features=tf.train.Features(feature={
        'encoded_img': tf.train.Feature(bytes_list=tf.train.BytesList(value=[byte_img])}))
    writer.write(example.SerializeToString())

    # Read img from file
    dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(<img_file>)
    dataset = dataset.map(parse_img_fn)
```

The `parse_img_fn` may be condensed to the following:

```
def parse_img_fn(serialized_example):
    features = tf.parse_single_example(serialized_example, feature_map)
    image = features['encoded_img']
    image = tf.image.decode_bmp(image, channels=3) # This is where the decoding fails
    features['encoded_img']

    return features
```

Comment: Seems the question is just about encoding bmp images as you know how to read them. What is your use case of encoding it as bmp? Why not use png instead?

Comment: Good point! I didn't know png was a non-destructive compression algorithm, so therefore I tried to fix a bmp encryption. I will use png instead, then, so thanks!

Anyways, I still would like to know how tensorflow encrypts images, and if it is possible to encrypt bmp images. It would be a great opportunity to learn how it works under the hood!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<sup>in your comment, surely you mean *encode* instead of *encrypt*</sup>

The BMP [file format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format#File_structure) is quite simplistic, consisting of a bunch of headers and pretty much raw pixel data. This is why BMP images are so big. I suppose this is also why TensorFlow developers did not bother to write a function to encode arrays (representing images) into this format. Few people still use it. It is recommended to use PNG instead, which performs lossless compression of the image. Or, if you can deal with lossy compression, use JPG.

TensorFlow doesn't do anything special for encoding images. It just returns the bytes that represent the image in that format, similar to what matplotlib does when you do `save_fig` (except MPL also writes the bytes to a file).

Suppose you produce a numpy array where the top rows are 0 and the bottom rows are 255. This is an *array of numbers* which, if you think it as a *picture*, would represent 2 horizontal bands, the top one black and the bottom one white.

If you want to see this picture in another program (GIMP) you need to encode this information in a standard format, such as PNG. Encoding means adding some headers and metadata and, optionally, compressing the data.

---

Now that it is a bit more clear what encoding is, I recommend you work with PNG images.

```
with tf.gfile.FastGFile('image.png', 'rb') as f:
    # get the bytes representing the image
    # this is a 1D array (string) which includes header and stuff
    raw_png = f.read()

    # decode the raw representation into an array
    # so we have 2D array representing the image (3D if colour) 
    image = tf.image.decode_png(raw_png)

    # augment the image using e.g.
    augmented_img = tf.image.random_brightness(image)

    # convert the array back into a compressed representation
    # by encoding it into png
    # we now end up with a string again
    augmented_png = tf.image.encode_png(augmented_img, compression=9) 

    # Write augmented_png to file using tf.train.Example
    writer = tf.python_io.TFRecordWriter(<output_tfrecords_filename>)
    example = tf.train.Example(features=tf.train.Features(feature={
        'encoded_img': tf.train.Feature(bytes_list=tf.train.BytesList(value=[augmented_png])}))
    writer.write(example.SerializeToString())

    # Read img from file
    dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(<img_file>)
    dataset = dataset.map(parse_img_fn)
```

There are a few important pieces of advice:

- don't use `numpy.tostring`. This returns a *HUUGE* representation because each pixel is represented as a float, and they are all concatenated. No compression, nothing. Try and check the file size :)
- no need to pass back into python by using tf.Session. You can perform all the ops on TF side. This way you have an input graph which you can reuse as part of an input pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

There is no encode_bmp in the tensorflow main package, but if you import tensorflow_io (also a Google officially supported package) you can find the encode_bmp method there.

For the documentation see:
https://www.tensorflow.org/io/api_docs/python/tfio/image/encode_bmp