# Writing an encoded png to TFRecord

Tags: tensorflow

I have an image as a numpy array of shape HxWx3 that I'm trying to encode to png and write to the tfrecord. I'm encoding using `tf.image.encode_png`, which returns a `Tensor` of type `string`. How can I convert this tensor to a `BytesList`

```
    encoded_image = tf.image.encode_png(img)
example = tf.train.Example(features=tf.train.Features(feature={
    'height': _int64_feature(256),
    'width': _int64_feature(256),
    'image':  tf.train.Feature(bytes_list = tf.train.BytesList(value = [encoded_image])) 
}))
```

Here is the error that I'm getting

```
TypeError: <tf.Tensor 'EncodePng_58:0' shape=() dtype=string> has type Tensor, but expected one of: bytes
```

I guess I could write to a `.png` file and do a binary read to get the bytes but I want to avoid having to do that. Based on this post here [Tensorflow: How to encode and read bmp images?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50871281/tensorflow-how-to-encode-and-read-bmp-images) what I've done should work, but I'm getting the above error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to evaluate tensor inside tf.Session().

```
writer = tf.python_io.TFRecordWriter('test.tfrecords')
with tf.Session() as sess:
    str = sess.run(tf.image.encode_png(img))

example = tf.train.Example(features=tf.train.Features(feature={'image_raw': _bytes_feature(str)}))
writer.write(example.SerializeToString())
writer.close()
```

You can use numpy.tostring() without session,

```
str = img.tostring()
```

but it's expected to perform worse.

Comment: Evaluating inside the session works, although it is slow and takes a couple of seconds for each encoded png.  @Sharky can you suggest some improvements to make it faster? Also, I assume `str = img.tostring()` would lead to a raw image rather than an encoded one?

Comment: It's strange, for me, convertion of a directory of 1500 images took less than 10 sec. And resulting tfrecords file weights much less than with .tostring
Try using session on a whole directory. And try using compression parameter

Comment: @iOSnewbie - Did you find a faster way to run it inside session?